# TextView.setText() crashes my application on HTC one and Bluestacks

Tags: java, android, crash, settext

This question has been asked in various forms, but none of them apply to me.

Whenever I use the `setText` method, my application crashes, regardless or the arguments passed to it, this same thing happens on all three of my computers, and I can't find any solutions at all.

Please see the below code, (it is really simple, I am actually doing an introductory course to Java and android development)

I'd appreciate any help on this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //these are just examples to show the error
    int num1 = 30;
    int num2 = 50;
    int total = (num1 + num2)/2;

    TextView show = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtShow);
    show.setText(String.valueOf(total));


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Attach Logs so that we can help you better.

Comment: maybe You refer a wrong xml layout, or the view with id txtShow is no textView. But without seeing the crash report from logcat, nobody could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, once I removed it, it worked perfectly. I am not sure why it automatically generates that statement if it prevents the app from running. Anyway, Thanks for the help , it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way to see the `Exception`? It would probably be really helpful.

For example, a `NullPointerException` would make you understand that "show" is null.

Try this:

```
if (show != null) {
   show.setText("something");
}
```